# How to stop ListView from flickering upon timer refresh?

Tags: vb.net, listview

I have created a VB form which display's SQL data into a list view, the list view refreshes every few seconds to display new values when new data is entered into the SQL table. Everything works, however the annoying problem is the list view will flicker every time it refreshes. Is there a way to prevent it from flickering?

The current code I have below. Thanks

```
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Imports System.Drawing

Public Class Form1

Dim conn As SqlConnection
Dim cmd As SqlCommand
Dim da As SqlDataAdapter
Dim ds As DataSet
Dim itemcoll(100) As String

Private WithEvents tmr As New Timer With {.Interval = 500}
Private R As New Random

Private Declare Function LockWindowUpdate Lib "user32" (ByVal hwndLock As Long) As Long
Private Declare Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal dwMilliseconds As Long)

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    tmr.Start()
    Call GetData()

End Sub



Private Sub GetData()

    listview1.beginupdate

    ListView1.HeaderStyle = ColumnHeaderStyle.None
    Me.ListView1.View = View.Details
    Me.ListView1.GridLines = False
    Me.ListView1.AutoResizeColumns(ColumnHeaderAutoResizeStyle.ColumnContent)
    Me.ListView1.AutoResizeColumns(ColumnHeaderAutoResizeStyle.HeaderSize)

    Dim conn As New SqlConnection("Data Source=xxx;Initial Catalog=orders; User ID=xxx;Password=xxx")

    Dim strQ As String = String.Empty

    strQ = "SELECT productcode, productname, qty from dbo.ordertemptable"

    cmd = New SqlCommand(strQ, conn)
    da = New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
    ds = New DataSet
    da.Fill(ds, "dbo.ordertemptable")

    Dim i As Integer = 0
    Dim j As Integer = 0

    ' adding the columns in ListView
    For i = 0 To ds.Tables(0).Columns.Count - 1
        Me.ListView1.Columns.Add(ds.Tables(0).Columns(i).ColumnName.ToString())
    Next

    'Now adding the Items in Listview
    For i = 0 To ds.Tables(0).Rows.Count - 1

        For j = 0 To ds.Tables(0).Columns.Count - 1

            itemcoll(j) = ds.Tables(0).Rows(i)(j).ToString()
        Next

        Dim lvi As New ListViewItem(itemcoll)
        Me.ListView1.Items.Add(lvi)
        Me.ListView1.AutoResizeColumns(ColumnHeaderAutoResizeStyle.ColumnContent)

    Next
        listview1.endupdate
End Sub

Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick

    ListView1.Items.Clear()
    ListView1.Columns.Clear()
    Call GetData()
    Timer1.Interval = 1000
    Timer1.Enabled = True
    ListView1.Refresh()

End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: A big reason it flickers is because the code assigns the View property repeatedly.  Only do that once, belongs in the form constructor.  If it is still too noticeable then derive your own class from ListView and use Sub New to set the DoubleBuffered property to True.

Answer (score 1):

Use the BeginUpdate ListView method before updating and then EndUpdate ListView method after the new data is added.  This will prevent it from constantly refreshing as you add each item.

Comment: could you explain in a bit more detail on how to use this function, I'm no expert on this. Thanks

Comment: @anthony : Before you start updating the contents of the `ListView` call `ListView1.BeginUpdate()`, then when you're done updating it call `ListView1.EndUpdate()` (i.e. in the beginning and end of `GetData()`). It's as simple as that. The MSDN documentation has an example of it: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.beginupdate(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @Visual Vincent: I added it to the beginning and end get data function, but the list view is still refreshing constantly. I am update the code above, am I doing it wrong?

Comment: If you tick the timer every second then it's going to refresh constantly.

Comment: @ A Friend: This is because I need it to constantly update as the user is entering data into the SQL table.